# Can an apple Shortcut script prompt for an audio recording then continue with that as input?

Tags: ios, macos, applescript, apple-watch

I want to make a Shortcut for OSX/iOS/Apple-Watch that would prompt for an audio recording then, in my use case, send that recording on to an endpoint. Is part or all of this possible? I realize it may need to involve an app I create, but I would prefer not to have to do that. Since it would be a Siri command eventually, I am assuming that, if this is possible, a pause will stop the audio input section of the script. Thanks!